# Preserving screen dimensions for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I just started learning web design, and I am coming across a couple different problems. Specifically, scaling for different screen sizes. I want the length to width ratio of the site to be constant regardless of the actual screen size. I know that this would mean that there would be dead space on the sides of the browser of a screen that does not fit this ratio precisely, but that is ok. I would like to know whether there is a way to enforce this constant length to width ratio. Presumably, this would fix my scaling issues with minimal additional work. I am on a deadline, so I cannot completely reimplement my positioning attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* use CSS units that are relative to the viewport. Simply enough, these are called '**[Viewport Units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)**' and are denoted by `vh` for height and `vw` for width. A `width` of `100vw`will ensure that the content is the exact same size as the viewport, regardless of how wide the viewport is.

However, what you're *probably* looking for are **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. These are 'sections' of your CSS that trigger at certain viewport breakpoints. Typically, you have one trigger for desktops, one for laptops, one for tablets, and one for mobile phones. There's a full list of media queries for standard devices [**available at CSS Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Most web development frameworks incorporate media queries by default, and opt for one of two approaches -- either giving priority to display on the widest screen (desktop-first) or the smallest (mobile-first). Depending on how you think your visits will most often view your website (hint: mobile), you can create the design of the website to primarily focus on those devices, with less time spent designing for larger devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, or `vmax`. They are scaled 0 to 100 like percentages, but always in relation to the viewport, not to the containing element. So if you do `width: 100vw; height: 50vw;` it's always going to look the same. You can also do fixed units like `mm`, `cm`, etc. You can do media queries too, but your application might need to be rotation aware.